# dependent nullify fails in a particular scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

These are the two models that i have.

One(:id, :two_nd_id) and 
Two(:id, :nd_id)

**Associations**

1) One belongs_to :two, :foreign_key => 'two_nd_id', :primary_key => 'nd_id'

2) Two has_many :one, :foreign_key => 'two_nd_id', :primary_key => 'nd_id', :dependent => :nullify

Now, when i try to delete an object of Two it raises an error,

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'one.nd_id' in 'where clause': 
UPDATE `one` SET `two_nd_id` = NULL WHERE `one`.`two_nd_id` = 'xxxxx' AND `one`.`nd_id` IS 
NULL
```

I dont get why `'one'.'nd_id' IS NULL` is checked at all ! Help me out. Thanks in advance

Note - :dependent => :destroy worked fine !

Answer (score 0):

Please say what your primary key for each model really is first.

Other than that:

First, I don't think you need to have `:primary_key => 'nd_id'`

Second, you should have `Two has_many :ones`, note the "s"

Third, why are both foreign key specified as "two_nd_id"? One of them is wrong.